# Joi validate array of objects, such that only one object has specific property

Tags: javascript, validation, joi

I've been reading the [Joi API doc](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v8.0.5/API.md) for a while & though I suspect what I want to do is possible, I'm not seeing the solution.

Given the following, how can I validate that only one `thing` has the `special` property:

```
let thing = {
  name: Joi.string(),
  special: Joi.boolean(),
}

let manyThings = {
  things: Joi.array().items(thing),
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're okay with having the first item in the array be the object that has the `special` property, you can use [array.ordered](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/master/API.md#arrayorderedtype) and define a second schema for the subsequent objects.

```
var joi = require('joi');

var thingSchmea = joi.object().keys({
    name: joi.string().required(),
    special: joi.boolean().required()
});

var thingWithoutSpecialSchema = joi.object().keys({
    name: joi.string().required()
});

var manyThingsSchema = joi.array().ordered(thingSchmea.required()).items(thingWithoutSpecialSchema);


var t = [
    {
        name: 'cuthbert',
        special: true
    },
    {
        name: 'roland',
        special: true
    },
    {
        name: 'jake'
    },
    {
        name: 'susan'
    }
];

var result = joi.validate(t, manyThingsSchema);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

The variable `t` will fail validation because the second item in the array has a `special` property.

Comment: great names! Totally need to reread that series! I suspected there wasn't a straightforward way to validate complex cases like this via Joi; thus I've added  another validation layer for cases not suited for Joi.